# LINQ How to Show Average of all results in GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to write a query which returns the average time spent on a job in a ticketing system.
There are multiple time logs in each job so I need to group by the SO Number and then somehow get an average of all of the results.

The current query returns a list of every service order and the total minutes spent to the job.

How do I make this show me the average minutes spent on each job?

```
from so in TblServiceOrders
from sologs in TblSOLogs.Where(x => x.SONumber == so.SONumber).DefaultIfEmpty()


where so.DateClosed >= new DateTime(2013,07,01) 
where so.DateClosed <= new DateTime(2013,07,02)
where sologs.ElapsedHours != 0 || sologs.ElapsedMinutes != 0

group new { sologs.ElapsedHours, sologs.ElapsedMinutes } by so into g
select new { 
g.Key.SONumber,
elapsed = g.Average (x => (x.ElapsedHours == null ? 0 : x.ElapsedHours * 60) + (x.ElapsedMinutes == null ? 0 : x.ElapsedMinutes))
}
```

==EDIT==

This looks like it is getting close but it is giving me an average of every time log and not an average of the total time logs in each SO.

Please help?

```
from so in TblServiceOrders
join sologs in TblSOLogs on so.SONumber equals sologs.SONumber

where so.DateClosed >= new DateTime(2013,07,01) 
where so.DateClosed <= new DateTime(2013,07,03)
where sologs.ElapsedHours != 0 || sologs.ElapsedMinutes != 0

group sologs.SONumber by sologs into g
group new {g.Key.ElapsedHours, g.Key.ElapsedMinutes} by "Total" into t

select t.Average (x => (x.ElapsedHours == null ? 0 : x.ElapsedHours * 60) + (x.ElapsedMinutes == null ? 0 : x.ElapsedMinutes))
```

Comment: the shown query doesn't compile, does it ? You group by ElapsesHours and ElapsedMinutes, and use Key.SoNumber... You should group by SoNumber, no ?

Comment: Is this query supposed to work on a database or on in-memory collections ? Because if it is supposed to work on a database you have big problems in it.

Comment: It's supposed to run on a database and it runs okay, It just returns each SO with the total. The query is not supposed to work, It is where I am up to in my attempt to get the results.

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I might have it working. Feedback is welcome in case there is an error with the results?

Answer (score 0):

I've worked it out for the most part, Hopefully this can help others.

The first part of my question was getting all the results into the same group without a distinct value to `Group By`. This was achieved by declaring a string in the `Group By` such as "Total".

For Example:

```
group tblName.FieldName by "Example" into group1
```

For the second part I needed to perform a `Group By` on the `Sum` of another `Group By`. Below is an example of declaring two new values generated from the `Sum` of a `Group By`:

```
group new { tblName.FieldName1, tblName.FieldName2} by tblName into group1
group new { SumField1 = g.Sum (x => x.FieldName1), SumField2 = g.Sum (x => x.FieldName2) } by "Totals" into newgroup2
```

Here is a full example of the code I ended up writing, It works well in `LINQPad` but I am still working on implementation into a `Visual Studio` `C#` `DataGridView`.

```
from so in TblServiceOrders
join sologs in TblSOLogs on so.SONumber equals sologs.SONumber

where so.DateClosed >= new DateTime(2014,01,17) 
where so.DateClosed <= new DateTime(2014,01,17)
where sologs.ElapsedHours != 0 || sologs.ElapsedMinutes != 0

group new {sologs.ElapsedHours, sologs.ElapsedMinutes} by sologs.SONumber into g
group new {hours = g.Sum (x => x.ElapsedHours), mins = g.Sum (x => x.ElapsedMinutes)} by "Totals" into t

select new {
Average = t.Average (x => (x.hours * 60) + x.mins),
Count = t.Count ()
}
```